# Starting git bash gives error "bash: fork: retry: No child processes"

Tags: windows, git

When I right click a folder on windows and select 'Git Bash' I get the message:

```
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
bash-4.3$
```

I'm expecting the bash prompt to appear. Ideas?

Can type exit, to which it responds 'logout' but again hangs.

Comment: Did you retried after restart machine  ?

Comment: Bingo - that worked Govind thanks. Very odd. Never had issues like this with git bash. Been using same version for months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the machine and tried out may you will resolve your problem.

Comment: If your problem has been resolve then Accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

As Govind pointed out in comments. Restarting the machine could help, in my case it did.